# C++ Multithreaded server help

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm working on a multithreaded server in c++ using boost-asio. Currently a design problem I'm running into deals with erasing a connection.

I have a single server instance which holds a vector of connection objects. These connections receive commands which I parse. One command in particular deals with sending data to ALL connections in my vector.

Now when a connection disconnects I'm currently erasing this connection from the vector and calling the destructor. It seems like I'm going to run into problems when someone 'SendAll' at the same time someone 'Disconnect'.

Could anyone recommend a better design or just point me in the right direction? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever class maintains this vector of connections needs a [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html). Use `strand::post` or `strand::dispatch` when accessing, adding to, or removing from the vector. The [strand concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) is explained in detail in the documentation.

> A strand is defined as a strictly
>   sequential invocation of event
>   handlers (i.e. no concurrent
>   invocation). Use of strands allows
>   execution of code in a multithreaded
>   program without the need for explicit
>   locking (e.g. using mutexes).

Comment: @kisplit glad to help. Feel free to ask more questions about asio if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Is putting a lock around the vector not an option? Have every access to the vector first acquire a lock; that will prevent your race condition. As long as server connections don't come and go very frequently, it won't be a bottleneck.

Comment: you should prefer using an asio strand rather than mutex where possible.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I picked Sam's post since it uses strand from asio but I found your post extremely helpful too.