# boost::asio asynchronous operations and resources

Tags: c++, boost, asynchronous, boost-asio

So I've made a socket class that uses boost::asio library to make asynchronous reads and writes. It works, but I have a few questions.

Here's a basic code example:

```
class Socket
{
public:
    void doRead()
    {
        m_sock->async_receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(m_recvBuffer), m_from, boost::bind(&Socket::handleRecv, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error(), boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred()));
    }

    void handleRecv(boost::system::error_code e, int bytes)
    {
        if (e.value() || !bytes)
        {
            handle_error();
            return;
        }
        //do something with data read
        do_something(m_recvBuffer);

        doRead(); //read another packet
    }

protected:
    boost::array<char, 1024> m_recvBuffer;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint m_from;
};
```

It seems that the program will read a packet, handle it, then prepare to read another. Simple.
But what if I set up a thread pool? Should the next call to `doRead()` be before or after handling the read data? It seems that if it is put before `do_something()`, the program can immediately begin reading another packet, and if it is put after, the thread is tied up doing whatever `do_something()` does, which could possibly take a while. If I put the `doRead()` before the handling, does that mean the data in `m_readBuffer` might change while I'm handling it?

Also, if I'm using `async_send_to()`, should I copy the data to be sent into a temporary buffer, because the actual send might not happen until after the data has fallen out of scope? i.e.

```
void send()
{
    char data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    m_sock->async_send_to(boost::buffer(&data[0], 5), someEndpoint, someHandler);
} //"data" gets deallocated, but the write might not have happened yet!
```

Additionally, when the socket is closed, the handleRecv will be called with an error indicating it was interrupted. If I do

```
Socket* mySocket = new Socket()...
...
mySocket->close();
delete mySocket;
```

could it cause an error, because there is a chance that `mySocket` will be deleted before `handleRecv()` gets called/finished?

Comment: +1 for a good question, but in the future I'd suggest splitting it into separate questions on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of questions here, I'll try to address them one at a time.

> But what if I set up a thread pool?

The traditional way to use a thread pool with Boost.Asio is to invoke `io_service::run()` [from multiple threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html). Beware this isn't a one-size-fits-all answer though, there can be scalability or performance issues, but this methodology is by far the easiest to implement. There are many similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4734474/283302) on Stackoverflow with more information.

> Should the next call to doRead be before or after handling the read
>   data? It seems that if it is put before do_something(), the program
>   can immediately begin reading another packet, and if it is put after,
>   the thread is tied up doing whatever do_something does, which could
>   possibly take a while.

This really depends on what `do_something()` needs to do with `m_recvBuffer`. If you wish to invoke `do_something()` in parallel with `doRead()` using `io_service::post()` you will likely need to make a copy of `m_recvBuffer`.

> If I put the doRead() before the handling, does
>   that mean the data in m_readBuffer might change while I'm handling it?

as I mentioned previously, yes this can and will happen.

> Also, if I'm using `async_send_to()`, should I copy the data to be sent
>   into a temporary buffer, because the actual send might not happen
>   until after the data has fallen out of scope?

As the [documentation describes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send_to/overload1.html), it is up to the caller (you) to ensure the buffer remains in scope for the duration of the asynchronous operation. As you suspected, your current example invokes undefined behavior because `data[]` will go out of scope.

> Additionally, when the socket is closed, the `handleRecv()` will be called
>   with an error indicating it was interrupted.

If you wish to continue to use the socket, use `cancel()` to [interrupt outstanding](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/cancel/overload1.html) asynchronous operations. Otherwise, `close()` will work. The error passed to outstanding asynchronous operations in either scenario is `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`.